# Mockmvn assertion failing on LocalDateTime & List

Tags: spring-boot, jsonpath, mockmvc

I'm trying to assert a REST response and I'm facing some convertion erros ate time to compare `LocalDateTime` and `List<Scenario>`. It seems that JSON representation is not matching to the types being used.

Could someone explain me (or point me the documentation where I can extract it from) how this convertion works, please?

Model:

```
public class Control
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private Set<Scenario> scenarios = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
}

public class Scenario
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Response Body:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Control-ABC"
    "createdAt":"2021-05-31T10:11:12",       
    "scenarios":[
        {
           "id":1,
           "name":"Max"
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "name":"Average"
        }
    ]
}
```

Assertion:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/control/find/" + control.getId()))
      .andDo(print())
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", equalTo(control.getId()), Long.class))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", equalTo(control.getName())))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdAt", is(control.getCreatedAt()), LocalDateTime.class))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.scenarios", hasItems(control.getScenarios())));
```

Erros:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.createdAt"
Expected: is <2021-05-31T10:11:12>
     but: was "2021-05-31T10:11:12"


java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.scenarios"
Expected: (a collection containing <[Scenario(id=1, name=Max), Scenario(id=2, name=Average)]>)
 but: a collection containing <[Scenario(id=1, name=Max), Scenario(id=2, name=Average)]> mismatches were: [was <{id=1, name=Max}>, was <{id=2, name=Average}>]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your test harness can't convert types between `LocalDateTime` and string.  You'll need to do that conversion for it.

```java
...
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdAt", control.getCreatedAt().toString()))
...
```